# Normal User Control in DNN

Tags: dotnetnuke

In DNN, when one is developing a custom module, the user controls for the custom module are normally inherited from a special base class called '**PortalModuleBase**' in DNN Framework.

**Is it possible to not inherit** the custom module user controls from this special DNN base class, **but just create a regular user control** having its own edit and view logic, that inherits from UseControl .Net Framework base class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible, yes, but then you would lose the benefits of DNN. The PortalModuleBase class inherits from the regular .NET base class, it just provides an added layer with information like TabId (page id), UserInfo (user properties) and other various things that DNN modules regularly use.